# WPF (c#) - set position of a TextBox to the position of a selected ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, position, selecteditem

I'm trying to simulate inline editing in a listbox, by spawning a textbox at the position of the selected listbox item.

I use this function to get the doubleclicked(selected) item:

```
void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Control sourceControl = (ListBox)sender;

    UIElement element = (UIElement)sourceControl.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(sourceControl));

    while(element != sourceControl)
    {
        if(element is ListBoxItem)
        {
            // reference to the selected item
            ListBoxItem selectedItem = (ListBoxItem)element;

            // the textbox
            inlineTextEditBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            inlineTextEditBox.Text = (string)((ListBoxItem)element).Content;
            inlineTextEditBox.Focus();

            return;
        }
        element = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to set the textbox to the selected item? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you not use a datagrid? This functionality is already included for datagrid text columns

Comment: Thanks for bringing the datagrid control to my attention. I'll definitely have a look at it.